# Ho to angle sweep gradient in drawables?

Tags: android, gradient, drawable

I trying to implement loading image with fading tail using sweep gradient, but i can't find how manage sweep gradient angle. Property "angle" does nothing for this type of gradients

[image].

Can anybody give me a hint?

[image: weird sweep gradient]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there is no such thing as "sweep gradient angle". Required result could be implemented using not so intuitive way. You should place marks with different color and offset, then android will make arc of gradient between current and next closest clockwise mark. The trick is you can place multiple marks, and 0 offset not on the top, but on the right.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="60dp"
android:height="60dp"
android:viewportWidth="60"
android:viewportHeight="60">
<path
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:pathData="M28.8996,4.2819C15.2093,4.8575 4.2857,16.1402 4.2857,29.9731C4.2857,44.1747 15.7984,55.6874 30,55.6874C44.2016,55.6874 55.7143,44.1747 55.7143,29.9731C55.7143,16.2702 44.9948,5.0694 31.4854,4.301L31.7288,0.0222C47.4939,0.9189 60,13.9848 60,29.9731C60,46.5417 46.5685,59.9731 30,59.9731C13.4315,59.9731 0,46.5417 0,29.9731C0,13.8336 12.7441,0.6716 28.7196,0L28.8996,4.2819Z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient
            android:centerX="30"
            android:centerY="31.5803"
            android:gradientRadius="68.0442"
            android:type="sweep">

            <item
                android:color="#3FFFFFFF"
                android:offset="0" />

            <item
                android:color="#5FFFFFFF"
                android:offset="0.25" />


            <item
                android:color="#AFFFFFFF"
                android:offset="0.5" />

            <item
                android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:offset="0.75" />

            <item
                android:color="#00FFFFFF"
                android:offset="0.75" />

            <item
                android:color="#3fFFFFFF"
                android:offset="1" />
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
```

[image]